# Unwanted temporary tables ingested into Hevo pipeline?

Tags: database, google-bigquery, amazon-rds, etl, pipeline

We have been using Hevodata for moving data from Amazon RDS MySQL to BigQuery. However, even when "Ingest New Objects" have been turned off, temporary tables keep being ingested into the pipeline.

We only need one table from MySQL at the moment, and it's only 1.7M rows, but these temp tables are large, and there are over 400 of them! Even after deleting the old pipeline and creating a new one, these tables still appear.

It's so frustrating, especially since we don't have a data engineer and their support seems too chill about my saying that this is urgent for us. Our website is built on Magento, the table we need is sales_orders, and unwanted tables are created during indexing jobs.
Does anyone have a clue why this is?

Comment: When you say "turn off" did you mean "paused? As mentioned in this document? PAUSED: The ingestion has been paused and will not fetch data until resumed. https://docs.hevodata.com/pipelines/pipeline-concepts/data-ingestion/data-ingestion-statuses/

Comment: No, this is an option for ingesting new tables, so when I turn this off, it is displayed "Include New Objects: False". I did not pause the entire pipeline.